# Fedora25 Php 5.6 gd soap Mysql 5.x and PhpMyAdmin

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, php-5.6, php-gd, fedora-25

I am new to linux.

I have successfully installed following modules on Centos7 but I have problem with Fedora25. I have checked google etc but theres only instructions for Fedora24.

I am amble to install php7 or php5.6 from remi repo but I cant find php56-gd, php56-soap.
Afterall If I am trying to install phpmyadmin system tries to install phpmyadmin with php7 libraries.

Finally I have used

```
dnf --enablerepo=remi install php56 php56-php-common php56-php-cli php56-php-fpm php56-php-gd php56-php-intl php56-php-mbstring php56-php-mcrypt php56-php-opcache php56-php-pdo php56-php-pear php56-php-pecl-apcu php56-php-imagick php56-php-pecl-xdebug php56-php-pgsql php56-php-xml php56-php-mysqlnd php56-php-pecl-jsonc php56-php-pecl-zip php56-php-process php56-runtime
```

But now I have 503 error on phpinfo() page.

```
[proxy:error] [pid 17800] (2) No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /opt/remi/php56/root/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17800] [client:192.168.0.109:51198] AH1079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

/opt/remi/php56/root/var/run/php-fpm/ exists but its empty

Can anyone help me to install this ?

Comment: It seems the php56-php-fpm service is not running.

Comment: systemctl start  php56-php-fpm  - now works THANKS !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

> I cant find php56-gd, php56-soap

You need php56-php-gd and php56-php-soap.

> But now I have 503 error on phpinfo() page.

Not enough information.

My [workstation](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation) is running Fedora 25 with php56 (and other versions), without issue.

Comment: php56-php-gd and php56-php-soap. - works. If i type phpinfo.php + 2 letters page i am getting only letters php seems not work if I press F5 then 503